# Python: find and marge pdf with similar name

Tags: python, pdf

I have a folder with more than 20K files pdf and I would need to check if there are multiple files that have the same 16 initial digits and marge them

Basically, the file within the folder are like this:

- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
- yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_1
- yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_2
- zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
- zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz_1

and I would need to merge the files above to

- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy (containing the 3 files)
- zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz ( containing the 2 files)

I found a code that halps to do a glob based on the first 16 digits but not sure how to integrate in the PDF marge i would normally use

```
filelist = glob.glob(_filepath_) 
        dictionary = {}  
        for x in filelist:  
            key = x[:16] # The key is the first 16 characters of the file name
            group = dictionary.get(key,[])
            group.append(x)  
            dictionary[key] = group
```

this is the script I would normally use to marge pdf

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

source_dir = './PDF Files/'
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        #print(item)
        merger.append(source_dir + item)

merger.write(source_dir + 'Output/Complete.pdf')       
merger.close()
```

Is anyone able to assist?

thanks a lot